# Use a case expression on resultset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to write a SQL query with case and the conditions of the case is dependent on whether any records are found on a sub-query.

```
Select 
  Case When (Another Select statement which may return results) 'True'
  Else 'False'
  End As Has_Results
From TBL_ABC
```

Comment: provide your full query and sample data as well as expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `EXISTS` condition in a `CASE` expression:

```
Select Case 
    When Exists (
        Another Select statement which may return results
    ) 
    Then 'True'
    Else 'False'
End As Has_Results
From TBL_ABC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use EXISTS:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN exists(other query) THEN 'True'  --Subquery has record   
    ELSE 'False'                          --Subquery has not record     
END;
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the already existing answer?